# fade animation issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

what causes that [@fadeInOut] that it only works at the first load of the page when I toggle the isExpanded to hide and show content because of the [@fadeInOut] the content are no longer showing...any idea what causes this and the alternatives or solution. Thanks.

#htmlt code

```
 <div *ngIf="isExpanded" [@fadeInOut]>
    <ng-content select="[Content]"></ng-content>
  </div>
```

#ts

```
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
        state('0, void', style({
            opacity: 0
        })),
        state('1, *', style({
            opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('1 => 0', animate('10ms ease-out')),
        transition('0 => 1', animate('100ms ease-in')),
        transition('void <=> *', animate('200ms ease-in'))
    ]),
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue, please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-fade-in-out-paf66f)

Comment: Hi Sir , so what is the solution ?

Comment: cant seem to understand on my end , why it only loads at first

Comment: What do you mean it only loads at first. Your question needs to be more clear, like with screenshots describing what the issue is!

Comment: the fade only works at firs toggle after that it no longer loads the content

Comment: so for example based on your stackblitz id I click done it will show the fields but if I keep clicking done button the content are no longer showing

Comment: Its due to the *ngIf right, its hiding when the condition is false!

Comment: so what is the alternative to fade ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247863/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-tim-launders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its due to the dynamic content through `ng-content` instead of `*ngIf` use `[hidden]` You need to invert the if condition though!

```
<div class="page-section-card-content-container" [hidden]="!isExpanded" [@fadeInOut]>
    <ng-content select="[Content]"></ng-content>
  </div>
```

#ts

```
 trigger('fadeInOut', [
        state('0, void', style({
            opacity: 0
        })),
        state('1, *', style({
            opacity: 1
        })),
        transition('1 => 0', animate('10ms ease-out')),
        transition('0 => 1', animate('100ms ease-in')),
        transition('void <=> *', animate('200ms ease-in'))
    ]),
```

Comment: the issue is that the   opacity: 0 is always zero after first toggle it no longer get back to state 1

Comment: @TimLaunders ok, hope it solved!

Comment: hidden makes the data show now but the thing is it is now the animation that is not working xd

Comment: See that if you use state (and not :enter :leave aliases) you should use in the way `[@fadeInOut]="variable"` see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations#defining-animations-and-attaching-them-to-the-html-template)

Comment: still the same result